# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement os (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for os

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

i'm creating a face mask detector and i want to install the os module

i run this in the console:

> pip install os

but i got this error:

> Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement os (from versions: none)
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for os

using spyder(python 3.9)

Comment: Why do you need to install `os`? It should already be installed

Comment: Because i need to use the machine camera

Comment: I didn't mean what you're gonna use it for, but why it's not already present in your python installation. Are you saying that you're getting import errors if you simply do `import os`?

Comment: `os` is installed with `Python` and you don't have to install it with `pip`. And you can't even do it because it is not avaliable by `pip`. But why do you need `os` for `face mask detector` ? `os` means `Operation System` and it have functions to work operation system's functions like file's path `os.paths`, etc. Maybe you means `cv` for `Computer Vision` which could more useful for `face mask detector`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`os` is part of Python core, there should be no need to install it with pip.

You can import it already.